# How can I convert this Gradio file upload code into folder path taking one?

Tags: python, huggingface, gradio

There is this gradio code that allows you to upload images. I prefer entering folder path as a text input.

It works but instead of this one, I want to convert it into a directory path taking one

```
  reference_imgs = gr.UploadButton(label="Upload Guide Frames", file_types = ['.png','.jpg','.jpeg'], live=True, file_count = "multiple")
```

I tried below one but it didn't work

```
reference_imgs = gr.inputs.FilePicker(label="Select folder with Guide Frames", type="folder")
```